# Calculate tension force in ropes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

Attached is a picture of the problem I'm facing. I have two main questions -

The scenario given does not have gravity, so does the weight force equal the object's mass?

Also, is tension force additive on each rope? Like on rope A, I can determine Pod 2's tension force to be 1M. Pod 1's weight is 2M, so is rope A's tension force 3M?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tension force should be 0. The masses are not accelerating, they are all moving with constant speed. Why would there be any tension in the ropes when you are in space and the problem says no gravity?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It seems I misunderstood the relationship between acceleration and tension. Thanks

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Don't forget to accept the answer and close the question.